# Reusable Django Application Uninstallation

Tags: python, django, django-apps, python-packaging

I am creating a Django reusable app, which creates some models and performs certain views on those models.
So I make it as a python package and use it in an independent project. At some point, if I want to uninstall this app, it should remove the tables that it had created in the project's database.
Is it possible to make my python package in such a way to remove all of my app's footprint?

Comment: You can use `./manage.py migrate my_app zero` to remove all the tables used by an app. If there's a hook somewhere in your package uninstaller, maybe you can somehow use it there. But be careful about having other apps with migrations dependent on this one, since those migrations will be rolled back too.

Comment: @malberts ./manage.py migrate my_app zero has to be used while running my project. I want to make my app's build self-sufficient, such that as soon as any project uninstalls this app, the tables created by the app gets deleted with it, without executing any command in the project. Basically, pip uninstall my_app should delete the tables my_app had created.

Comment: How do you propose for pip to know which projects are using this app? You could potentially have a 100 Django websites, so the uninstaller would somehow have to be aware of them. And even then, should `pip install` automatically add it to `settings.py` of every possible Django project in the current environment too? What I'm trying to get at: do you really want a totally generic uninstallation system, or is it meant only for your own internal project?

Comment: Also, if it is meant for other people as well, what if they *don't* want those tables deleted? By leaving the tables there I can re-enable the app and have the old data again. Or is this not a use case for you?

Comment: @malberts I just want to ensure that my_app does not leave behind any footprint (data or tables) once it is uninstalled from a project. I am planning to make a globally available app and not something just for my internal projects.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, even if it was possible. Users of an app wouldn't expect it to automatically delete tables. Quite simply, that's not its responsibility: the data belongs to the project.

Comment: @DanielRoseman fair point. I was just wondering if this was possible!

Comment: technically speaking this would not be possible in a generic reliable way. And as Daniel mentioned even if you managed to make it work, everyone would hate you for messing with there precious data.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay!